# VB.Net Countdown - Timer has delay

Tags: vb.net, timer, delay, countdown

So I just created a Countdown which updates each timer tick but using a real countdown to compare the one I coded has a small delay. After 1 Minute its like 3 Seconds slower than a normal timer.

The weird thing is that it works fine if I set the Interval to something above 1000 = update each second.
But everything below 1000 has a delay and I want a timer with milliseconds, update each 0.1 secon = Interval 100.

Thats the code I have so far (It looks messy because it switches the color of the label once it reaches a certain amount of time left)

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label1.Text = "Time left" & count

    If count >= 12 Then
        If change = False Then
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
            change = True
        End If
        Timer1.Interval = 2000
        count = count - 2

    ElseIf count <= 11.5 And count >= 7.5 Then
        If playaudio = False Then
            playaudio = True
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        Timer1.Interval = 100
        count = count - 0.1

    ElseIf count <= 7.5 And count >= 0 Then
        count = count - 0.1
        If changes = False Then
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
            changes = True
        End If

    ElseIf count <= 0 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Timer2.Enabled = True
        Timer2.Start()
        playaudio = False
        changes = False
        change = False
        count = 100
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any ohter way that the timer doesnt delay?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the actions you take are delaying the next timer.

One way to work around the problem would be to set the timer to something like 10ms. At each tick, you check if the previous refresh is older than the desired delay.

Or you can set the timer in another thread, which will not be affected by the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Forms timers are notoriously inaccurate.  Use a stopwatch to measure time and the Timer to update the display.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Stpw.Start()
        Timer1.Start() 'I have it set to 100ms.
    End Sub

    Private CountDown As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0#)
    Private Stpw As New Stopwatch

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Stpw.Elapsed >= CountDown Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Stpw.Stop()
            Label1.Text = "Blast Off"
        Else
            Dim ToGo As TimeSpan = CountDown - Stpw.Elapsed
            Label1.Text = ToGo.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.f")

            Select Case ToGo.TotalSeconds

            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Start with this and you'll see how it works.  Your color coding can probably go in the Select.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a restructuring of your code. It's like dbasnett's stopwatch, except it uses a class you're more likely to be familiar with, to introduce the concept that "instead of using a timer and measuring time passage by adding up (or taking away) every time it ticks (which is subject to cumulative errors), pick a moment in time and regularly calculate how far away it is":

```
'code that starts a minute countdown

'class level property noting the end time
Private _endDateTime as DateTime


    'the end time is a minute away
    _endDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1)

    'we only need one timer
    timer1.Start()




Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim count = (_endDateTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds 'how far away is the end time?

    Label1.Text = $"Time left {count:0.0}s"

    If count <= 0 Then 'reset
        Timer1.Stop()
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse   
        playaudio = False
     
    Else If count <= 7.5 Then
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf count <= 11.5 Then
        playaudio = True
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow

    End If

End Sub
```

There is a lot of redundancy that can be removed in your code; we'll use a single timer, it can tick on whatever interval you like; if there is a label that is counting down with 0.1 second precision then we should maybe make it tick every 50ms

If you swap your ifs around you won't need to make them a range; if you're measuring less than, put the test for the smallest number first. Mostly these ifs won't enter at all, then when there is less than 11.5 seconds to go, the last if will start activating etc..

Nothing happens if you set a label color to be the same as it already is so you don't need that complicated Boolean setup with change/changes to make sure you only set the color once

The crucial thing is we have a fixed end point in time and every time we tick we work out how far away that is. We could tick 1000 times a second or once every 10 seconds, it doesn't matter; the end time is the end time is the end time